# Why is this quicksort algorithm implementation code getting Segmentation fault error?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, quicksort

I am working on implementing the quicksort algorithm on c language.When i compile,it says segmentation fault and i cannot find the cause of it.I looked up GeeksForGeeks about quicksort and it is my attempt at it.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    void swap(int *a,int *b){
        int temp=*a;
        *a=*b;
        *b=temp;
    }

    int partition(int arr[],int first,int last){
        int pivot=arr[last];
        int i=first-1;
        for(int j=first;j<=last-1;j++){
            if(arr[j]<=pivot){
            i++;
            swap(&arr[i],&arr[j]);
        }
     }
     swap(&arr[i+1],&arr[last]);
     return (i+1);
   }

   void quickSort(int arr[],int first,int last){
       int pivot=partition(arr,first,last);
       quickSort(arr,first,pivot-1);
       quickSort(arr,pivot+1,last);
   }



   int main() {
      int arr[]={1,8,3,9,4,5,7};
      int size=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
      quickSort(arr,0,size-1);
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
          printf("%d ", arr[i]);
      }
   }
```

I was expecting to see
        1 3 4 5 7 8 9
but i got Segmentation fault.

Comment: `quickSort` will always call `quickSort` which will always call `quickSort` which will always call `quickSort` which will always call `quickSort` which will always call `quickSort` which will always call `quickSort`, you have a recursion issue.

Comment: My compile even warns me: `'quickSort': recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow`

Comment: Yes,thank you, i fixed it by adding if(first<last) inside the void quickSort().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `quickSort`, you need to check that `first` is less than `last`:

```
   void quickSort(int arr[],int first,int last)
   {
       if(first < last)
       {
           int pivot=partition(arr,first,last);
           quickSort(arr,first,pivot-1);
           quickSort(arr,pivot+1,last);
       }
   }
```

You might also give attribution to GeeksForGeeks, as this code looks extremely similar to theirs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a base case on quicksort() call, because on the way it's written it will call infinitely and leads to a segmentation fault.